# Syntax Error when retrieving data from database by joining two tables in Hibernate Sql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, navicat

```
String query ="From transaction JOIN outlet transaction.outlet_ref_id = outlet.outletid WHERE(transaction.added_date_time between'"+sdate+"' and '"+edate+"') and (outlet.merchant ="+merchantId+")";
```

This is the query I'm using to retrieve data from the data base. This is working when I'm using this query in Navicat and gives data. But I'm using this as a hibernate query it gives following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write query Link : `from Company as comp inner join comp.employees as emp`.
`Company as comp` means  `entityName as referenceName`.

`From Transaction t JOIN Outlet o t.outlet_ref_id = o.outletid WHERE(t.added_date_time between'"+sdate+"' and '"+edate+"') and (o.merchant ="+merchantId+")`

use Entity name on `Transaction`

for more refer :

http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-hql-associations-and-inner-join-left-outer-join-right-outer-join-cross-join-example

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/hql/joins.php

Comment: please share your `transaction` and `outlet` entity code and also share java code where you are executing Query